# Copying Public Key from AWS EC2 Ubuntu Instance - set up sftp only user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sftp, putty, ssh-keys

I'm trying to set up an sftp only user for my Amazon EC2 instance. Good tutorial on this [here](http://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/setting-up-an-sftp-site-on-amazon-web-services-ec2-creating-an-account-to-share-with-a-third-party-and-restricting-that-account-to-allow-only-sftp/).

I am having a bit of trouble at this step:

```
Using the AWS Management Console, generate a new key pair for the third-party user.
Using puttygen, import the new key (keyname.pem) and copy its public key.
On the server, create the .ssh directory for the new user:
    sudo mkdir /home/newusername/.ssh
Paste the public key into /home/newusername/.ssh/authorized_keys.
```

Creating the key in AWS Management Console, no problem. It allows me to download and save the private key. I'm understanding the next step to mean import the the key from my EC2 instance to my local machine, copy the public key, and then paste it into the specified file.

Question is, how do I import the keypair using PuttyGen and copy the public key on my local machine? will it be a separate file from the private key?

PS both my local machine and ec2 instance are Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: to 'import' with puttygen means to convert your pem file to ppk as so: `sudo puttygen ./.ssh/keyfile.pem -o ./.ssh/keyfile.ppk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using puttygen is one of way of doing it, but I believe it's just easier to use `ssh-keygen` from a linux box to generate the private/public key pair.

From a linux box as 'root':

```
$ adduser myuser
$ su myuser -
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Your private/public key pair will be /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa (private) and /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (public)

Now just paste the content of id_rsa.pub into /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys in the machine where you are running your sftp server.  Make sure the `authorized_keys` file has `600` permissions.

Comment: Is there a way to add a key to to my current user or do I need to create that new user?

Comment: You can do either or both. Just run `ssh-keygen` as the user that you want to use.

Comment: i've done this and added the public key to ec2. Do you know how I would then use these keys to sftp into ec2 from my local machine?  I've seen `sftp -o IdentityFile=newkeypair1.pem newusername@ec2-hostname.amazonaws.com`. Do I need to convert the private file to .pem or something?

Comment: Use `sftp -i <your new user identity file> newusername@ec2-hostname.amazonaws.com`

Comment: cool yea, no experience with this, thanks for your help. also had to `sudo service ssh restart` to make sure looking for proper keys.